# Uninstall my application without UAC dialog?

Tags: windows-10, nsis, uninstallation, uac

My very own application is being installed by users into the APPDATA folder, without requiring any admin permissions.

This works very well.

When uninstalling my application through the Windows 10 control panel, an UAC confirmation message box appears:

[image]

*(German only, sorry)*

Both my (NSIS) installer and (NSIS) uninstaller are Authenticode-signed with both SHA-1 and SHA-256.

The uninstaller's manifest contains:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
```

I.e. it does not enforce to run with administrative privillegs.

Still, the (in my opinion unnecessary) UAC dialog box appears.

**My question:**

Am I, as a setup creator, able to tell Windows 10 to uninstall my application without showing the UAC dialog?

**Update 1:**

In response to [Hans' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767240/uninstall-my-application-without-uac-dialog?noredirect=1#comment86551363_49767240), I do understand what he is saying, still other apps like e.g. this one from Microsoft *do* uninstall without any UAC dialog:

[image]

Or e.g.

[image]

Seems they all have in common that they are UWP applications.

Comment: That is not possible.  Uninstalling apps is just as risky as installing one.  Usually a lot more risky, a bad one can easily do a lot of damage by deleting too much, also crippling other programs.  Programmers tend to assume that UAC is was designed to stop them from doing their stuff.  Not at all.  The user needs to know when his machine is being messed with, that dialog tells him.  Providing the user with useful info is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. I do think I understand. Still, there _are_ many apps that acutally do uninstall, _without_ showing any UAC dialog. I've updated my question with an example.

Comment: UWP does not use the traditional MSI installer approach.  Feasible in no small part because a UWP app always runs in a security sandbox, must store their data in isolated storage and is not allowed to assume that anybody else installed the components they need.  There is rather a lot that a UWP app cannot do by design, so it is not a universal solution.

Comment: It is a bug in the settings app and Microsoft does not seem to care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in the settings app and there is not much you can do about it. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942181/windows-control-panel-requires-admin-privileges-when-uninstall-via-nsis/44002257#44002257) for details.