# NSIS VPatch cant find Registry value

Tags: installation, nsis, patch

I have a problem with patching my application.
Have installed my application with an installer written in NSIS. Saved the installation path in the registry with

`WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\APP" "InstallPath" $InstDir`

This works and I can find the key and value in the registry GUI after installation.

In my patch installer I use this function to find the install path:

```
!include "VPatchLib.nsh"
!include x64.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

; Show details
ShowInstDetails show

Function FindInstallPath
   ClearErrors
   ReadRegStr $0 HKLM Software\APP ""
   ${If} $0 != ""
       MessageBox MB_OK "Install path: $0"
       StrCpy $INSTDIR $0
       Return
   ${Else}
       MessageBox MB_OK "Path error: '$0'"
       Quit
   ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

No path is found, and the patch cannot be applied. If I try to read any other key, fx: `ReadRegStr $0 HKCU "Software\Realtek\Audio\RtkAudUService\General" "InstallPath"`, the value is returned as expected.

I am on a test user profile, that I created on my own computer. Both my installer and patch trigger the Windows UAC and I type in the admin password.

I really appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Andreas

**EDIT:**

Changed the function, in regard to Anders answer.

Also, this works when im on the admin, but not on a non-admin user.

Comment: Why are you talking about VPatch but you are just showing NSIS code? Where are you writing the value?

Comment: To put it into context. The problem is not related to VPatch (i think), but I do use VPatch as a plugin in the script.
The patching part is variable and seems to work on admin users, but on regular user profiles this function fails to read the registry.

Comment: I am writing the value in my initial install. Then, when patching I try to read it.

Comment: Admin vs user is a UAC issue, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetRegView 64` should not be used just because you are running on a 64-bit system. You should only use it if A) You are installing a 64-bit application. B) You need to read/write a Windows-specific registry value.

Usually when you can't find something you wrote it is because you are not using the correct registry view. Try [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which key you are writing to and where you are reading.

You should not really write to HKCU in elevated installers, use HKLM. When a non-admin user UAC elevates they end up with the administrators HKCU and profile!

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: I am getting some (to me) strange behaviour.

With Process Monitor i found the path that actually got the InstallPath written
`HKU\S-1-5-21-1880166722-1511875134-2720093845-1002\Software\APP\(Default)`
Which, from what you say, might be referring to the admin user.

Strangely enough, when i look in the registry GUI (on the user profile) the path that i requested it to be written on: `HKCU\Software\APP`, also has the value. Is there an explanation to this?


I will look into not writing the values in HKCU, but HKLM.

Comment: HKCU is a symlink to one of the keys in HKU. The S-1... string is the users SID.

Comment: The admin user, since the installer is elevated, right? Now i've tried to read the registry with the function in the updated question above. Process Monitor shows me that it is searching in this path: `HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\APP`. Is that normal?

I need to change my installer, which will take a bit of time, but i'll get back tomorrow!

Comment: WOW6432Node is the key 32-bit apps write to on 64-bit Windows by default, this is normal.

Comment: Should I then use this key in my path when I look for the value?

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem. Also had problems with the uninstaller but found this post: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942181/windows-control-panel-requires-admin-privileges-when-uninstall-via-nsis` and your help was well appreciated again. Thanks